# Java Lambda "Cyclic inference"

Tags: java, lambda, either

I'm not sure what's going on here, but the Java compiler seems unable to infer the type of this lambda I'm using (and IntelliJ is giving me a "Circular inference" warning). The lambda it's complaining about is the first argument of a function with the following signature:

`public <T> T apply(Function<byte[], T> ifPrimitive, Function<List<TreeNode>, T> ifConstructed)`

and this is an example of how I'm using it:

```
value.apply((p) -> { return null; },
            (c) -> {
                // Process the object a bit and return some data
            }
);
```

and here's the compiler error:

```
error: method apply in class TreeValue cannot be applied to given types;
        value.apply((p) -> { return null; },
             ^
  required: Function<byte[],T>,Function<List<TreeObject>,T>
  found: (p)->{ ret[...]ll; },(c)->{ for[...]} } }
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression missing return value)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>apply(Function<byte[],T>,Function<List<TreeObject>,T>)
1 error
:compileJava FAILED
```

For some context, I'm trying to implement a tree where each node is either an internal node and contains more nodes or contains raw data for processing. I've attempted to implement this with a kind of implementation of the Either monad with the left option being a byte[] containing the binary data for a leaf and the right option being a list of child nodes.

I understand the more standard approach for this might be a polymorphic tree but due to the way this tree is going to be consumed by other classes I don't feel that's the most applicable here.

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Comment: You have an extra `>` after `List<TreeNode>`.

Comment: Side note: You can replace `(p) -> { return null; }` with `p -> null`.

Comment: I assume this is in javac?

Comment: Nice catch, I made some minor edits to remove some potential red-herrings from the class names and guess I flubbed that edit. None of those changes should affect the behavior I'm seeing though, I'm 99.99% sure.

Comment: Compiles for me in javac and Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, the error is coming from javac, the "Cyclic inference" warning is coming from IntelliJ's linter.

Comment: Can you include a full snippet that causes this error?

Comment: Actually, the fact that you got it to compile got me what I needed to know. The second lambda does a tree search and one of it's execution paths didn't return a value (i.e. if it never found the node in question). I'm still not sure how that caused the compiler to throw an error on the first lambda, but whatever, it appears to be okay now!

Thanks!

Comment: Figured as much. Note the error message: *bad return type in lambda expression missing return value*.